# Given a record of functions, and a record of data of the types acted on by the functions, how to generically apply the function record?

Tags: haskell

The title is slightly inaccurate as my particular case is a bit more involved: rather than the functions in the first record acting directly on values in the second record, they act on a list (or other traversable) of the values. The result of an application for a particular field returns a value of the same type as was in the field, we can assume, if that buys us anything.

An example would be something like:

```
data Foo = Foo {
  v1 :: Int
, v2 :: Double
}

data FooFuns = FooFuns {
  v1 :: [Int] -> Int
, v2 :: [Double] -> Double
}
```

So the goal now is to automatically construct e.g.

```
result = Foo {
  v1 = (v1 FooFuns) (v1 <$> listOfFoos)
, v2 = (v2 FooFuns) (v2 <$> listOfFoos)
}
```

Currently I'm wrapping up the function on a list of values as a `newtype` (so it can be used by [Higgledy](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/higgledy)'s `HKD`) and a GADT for the Traversable constraint, but this latter part may be unnecessary, or perhaps better modeled as a typeclass:

```
data TraversableFun a t where
  TraversableFun :: Traversable t => (t a -> a) -> TraversableFun t a
newtype ListFun a = ListFun {unTravFun :: TraversableFun [] a}

type RecSummaryFuns a = HKD a ListFun
```

Now `RecSummaryFuns a` should have the same "field names" (constructor arguments) as `a`. Ideally there would be a way to easily apply `sFuns` to `recs` below to get a single record out.

```
applyStatFuns :: Traversable t => RecSummaryFuns r -> t r -> r
applyStatFuns sFuns recs = ???
```

I'm also curious if this is the best way to model the situation: basically I'm applying summary statistics to values held in records, but I need a way to encapsulate those summary statistics for each type of record.

Answer (score 5):

> Now RecSummaryFuns a should have the same "field names" (constructor
>   arguments) as a

This answer uses [red-black-record](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record) to construct "generalized records" that have the same field names as the original `Foo` record. First we must auto-derive some [supporting typeclasses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record-2.1.0.2/docs/Data-RBR.html#g:8):

```
{-# LANGUAGE AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-partial-type-signatures #-} -- hide some scary types

import Data.RBR (FromRecord (..), Record, ToRecord (..), fromNP, insert, toNP, unit)
import Data.SOP (I (I), NP) -- from sop-core
import Data.SOP.NP (liftA2_NP, liftA_NP) --   useful functions for n-ary products
import GHC.Generics

data Foo
  = Foo
      { v1 :: Int,
        v2 :: Double
      }
  deriving (Show, Generic, FromRecord, ToRecord)
```

Now we can define a value of our generalized record, whose fields will hold functions. Sadly, we can't employ the usual record syntax:

```
newtype Func a = Func ([a] -> a) -- helper newtype encapsulating the function

type FooFunc = Record Func (RecordCode Foo) -- wrap every field in Func

exampleFunc :: FooFunc
exampleFunc =
      insert @"v1" (Func head) -- field names give with TypeApplications
    . insert @"v2" (Func last) -- same order as in the original record
    $ unit -- unit is the empty record
```

The next step is defining this *generic* apply function with the help of the [n-ary product](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#t:NP) datatype provided by [sop-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core):

```
applyFunc ::  _ => Record Func _ -> [r] -> r
applyFunc func foos =
  let foos_NP :: [NP I _] -- a list of n-ary products. I is an identity functor
      foos_NP = toNP . toRecord <$> foos
      listfoos_NP :: [NP [] _] -- turn every component into a singleton list
      listfoos_NP = liftA_NP (\(I x) -> [x]) <$> foos_NP
      listfoo_NP :: NP [] _ -- a single n-ary product where each component is a list
      listfoo_NP = mconcat listfoos_NP
      func_NP :: NP Func _ -- turn the function record into a n-ary prod
      func_NP = toNP func
      resultFoo_NP_I :: NP I _ -- apply the functions to each list component
      resultFoo_NP_I = liftA2_NP (\(Func f) vs -> I (f vs)) func_NP listfoo_NP
   in fromRecord . fromNP $ resultFoo_NP_I -- go back to the nominal record Foo
```

Putting it all together:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
  print $
    applyFunc exampleFunc [Foo 0 0.0, Foo 1 1.0]
-- result: Foo {v1 = 0, v2 = 1.0}
```

Possible disadvantages of this solution are longer compilation times, and also the fact that turning the list-of-`Foo`s into a `Foo`-with-list-fields inside `applyFunc` might be inefficient for long lists.

We could ditch [red-black-record](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/red-black-record)—we are only using it to preserve field names in the generalized records—and rely on [sop-core](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core) / [generics-sop](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/generics-sop) directly; in that case field names would be handled differently—or we could simply rely on positional matching.

Comment: Type-level red-black records ... pretty wild (i see you are the author!). I'm going to chip away at this over the weekend, but one question: it looks like `NP` constraints the traversable to be a List, which might add to the inefficiencies if the input traversable was originally something other than a List, and this appears to be the case whether or not red-black-record is used, right?

Comment: `NP` (and `Record`) let you choose the type constructor in which to wrap every component. `NP I`, `NP Maybe`, `NP (Either String)`.... I used `[]` but one could choose something more suitable. Also, the key function here is `liftA2_NP` from sop-core, which performs "componentwise function application" http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sop-core-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-SOP-NP.html#v:liftA2_NP Something like it will likely exist in Higgledy as well, but I'm not familiar with that library.

Comment: I'm trying to go with this approach; to address the generic issues I'm having I asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58921905/how-to-fix-type-errors-including-cant-quantify-over-traversable-when-generi