# Why is a monoidal constraint implied by this function, even though only SemiGroup is listed as a constraint?

Tags: haskell

In the following stack script, I can't apply my `strangeHeadMay` function to a `NonEmpty` list, but it works fine on a regular list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
{- stack script --nix --resolver lts-13.6 -}

{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PartialTypeSignatures #-}
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-partial-type-signatures #-} -- hide some scary types

import           Control.Arrow                    ((&&&))
import           Control.Monad                    (join)
import           Data.Foldable                    (toList)
import           Data.Function                    ((&))
import           Data.Functor                     ((<&>))
import           Data.List.NonEmpty               (NonEmpty(..))
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty               as LNE
import           Data.Maybe                       (catMaybes)
import           Data.Tuple.Sequence              (sequenceT)


strangeHeadMay :: forall a t. (Semigroup (t a), _) => t a -> Maybe a
strangeHeadMay xs =
  let xsWrapped :: t (t a) = pure <$> xs -- <- Contrived example
      -- This is the functionality I actually need:
      xsMay :: Maybe (t a) = xsWrapped & (headMay &&& tailMay) & sequenceT
         <&> (\(h, t) -> foldr mappend h t)
   in do
    xs' <- xsMay
    xs' & toList & headMay

main :: IO ()
main = do
  let nexs :: NonEmpty (Maybe Double) = Nothing :| [Just (2.0)]
  let xs = LNE.toList nexs
  let xsHead = strangeHeadMay xs
  let nexsHead = strangeHeadMay nexs
  pure ()


headMay :: Foldable f => f a -> Maybe a
headMay = foldr (const . Just) Nothing

tailMay :: Foldable f => f a -> Maybe (f a)
tailMay = foldr (seq . Just) Nothing
```

The error is

```
/home/brandon/workspace/foldNEmaybes.hs:34:18: error:
    • No instance for (Monoid (NonEmpty (Maybe Double)))
        arising from a use of ‘strangeHeadMay’
    • In the expression: strangeHeadMay nexs
      In an equation for ‘nexsHead’: nexsHead = strangeHeadMay nexs
      In the expression:
        do let nexs :: NonEmpty (Maybe Double) = Nothing :| ...
           let xs = LNE.toList nexs
           let xsHead = strangeHeadMay xs
           let nexsHead = strangeHeadMay nexs
           ....
   |
34 |   let nexsHead = strangeHeadMay nexs
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Also, I must admit I'm not totally clear on why I need the partially typed signature, but changing `(Semigroup (t a), _)` to `(Semigroup (t a))` makes bad things happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even though `<>` and `mappend` do the same thing, you can only use the latter if you have a `Monoid` constraint, so one got added to your `_` in the type signature. To fix it, use `foldr (<>)` instead of `foldr mappend`.

And you don't need the hole in the type signature. You can write out what goes in it and it'll still work: `Applicative t` and `Foldable t`.

Comment: I spotted the `mappend` but I'm not satisfied with this explanation - because if that forced `t a` to be a `Monoid` (it may well do, I don't know the types involved here and haven't tried to work it out) I would expect the compiler to complain about the use of `mappend` in a function whose type signature only specifies `SemiGroup` - not to (it would seem) accept that definition and instead only complain when the function is evaluated.

Comment: @RobinZigmond But it does not only specify `Semigroup`, because of the partial specification (the `_` in the context) which tells the compiler "put here whatever constraint is needed to make this compile", i.e. a monoid constraint. At least, that's how I interpret the code.

Comment: Ah, thanks @chi, I confess I've never come across such a "hole" in a constraint and didn't know what it meant. And I really don't see the use, as it seems its only effect here was to cause a type error to be raised at a location other than the "true" one.

Comment: @RobinZigmond Just getting back to the computer and going over all this, but to see the original context of the odd type signature, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58889734/given-a-record-of-functions-and-a-record-of-data-of-the-types-acted-on-by-the-f/58890226#58890226 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58938566/3096687

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice `mappend` was not part of SemiGroup! To be fair I was spoiled by PureScript: https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/4.1.1/docs/Data.Semigroup#v:append; removing the hole and adding `Applicative t` and `Foldable t` works

Comment: @RobinZigmond The purposes for holes in type signatures is the same as for holes in expressions; it‘s for development when you‘re not quite sure what goes where but you know *part* of what you want, so you specify the bits you know and let the compiler figure out the rest (and then you can ask the compiler what it thinks the type signature should be given your partial constraint).

Comment: @Cubic thanks for explaining, I understand why that's useful for expressions, but for a type signature I would expect that if you simply leave off a constraint then GHC will tell you straight away what constraints are needed. Whereas from what the OP described it seems that the "hole" makes GHC silently add the necessary constraint, which as we've seen can merely lead to a type error elsewhere that's harder to trace.

Comment: @RobinZigmond If you just leave off a constraint, yes. But you can also leave off parts of a complicated constraint, which isn't quite as accessible.